# Memory reordering on single core

Tags: multithreading, memory, multicore

Most information about memory order refer to multicore/multicpu. Recently I asked a question related to re-ordering and the answer was is mainly occurs with multi-core. 
After running a small test on a single core CPU:

```
thread1()
{
 x++;
 y++;
}

thread2()
{
 if (x < y) 
   .... should not happen, because x is incremented first.
}
```

The x < y happens more frequently on a multicore weak ordered CPU, but it still happens at a single core CPU. (which I expected, but is not mentioned in most articles)

Any experiences, confirmation or explanation why It should not happen on a single core (although it seems to happen without any compiler optimization) ?

Comment: Out of order execution shouldn't effect single core execution.  The reads and writes will be seen by each thread up to date since there won't be any external CPU caching.  Atomicity is another issue entirely which may be what you are referring to.

Comment: So far I did not find any convincing explantion why it shoult not occur on a single core. Anyway ... I created the above test and incrementented a counter in the comparision. On a multicore it happened about 1k more often than on a single core. But on a single core (ARM) it did happen.

Comment: To clarify: compilers can rearrange your instructions to a small extent: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler, the processor can rearrange those instructions further: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution, and is not required to do writes to memory in the order you intend unless you tell it specifically to do so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier  None of this has to do with multithreading, these technologies date back to 1964, way before multithreading (late 1990s) or multicore (1984)

Comment: That‘s the same I think. However many articles and people are convinced it only causes problems at multi core/multi cpu.

Comment: The reordering you are seeing must be performed by the CPU. If the compiler did it you would see 0% or 100% reordering deterministically. One the one hand the question is moot because this code is invalid. On the other hand it would be interesting to know the answer.

Comment: Which specific ARM processor did you test this on?  Potential reordering is processor specific.

Comment: @usr.. I assume you say invalid because no synchronisation primitives are used. This was ommitted for the test.  It was tested on a single core cortex A5 an went wrong about 4 times out of 300k iterations.